# How could reduce the cpu instance for a long polling chat room service in GAE?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I want to host a web chat room service in GAE. I'm using the PHP to implement long polling, the PHP send keep alive packet to client to keep the connection every 30 seconds to avoid the front instance 60 seconds limitation.

Now I got a big problem:
 The instance hours is too high, because every user in the chat room is long polling, so each user takes a instance, if my user is more than 1K, 10K, 100K... the instals will increase to 1K, 10K, 100K... too many money I can't afford.

Does there has a better way to do this ? Use the channel API? But it's just available for JAVA and Python, it's not for PHP yet.

If I rewrite my service by python or java to use the channel API, it will reduce a lot of instance hours ? Otherwise I have to consider use Linode VPS.

Best regards,

Comment: if each users consumes an instance you are doing something wrong. You should be able to serve many users with a single instance.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood yes, but it's web chat service, the user MUST keep the connection for receive and send message realtime.

Comment: @JeffMorriss I think you might be under the mistaken assumption that each request is handled by a single instance. This is not the case. An instance can handle a good number of requests. That said, doing this with anything other than the Channel API is a bad idea. Don't do it. If you know PHP, you can learn enough Python to do the job within a few weeks. Why not try that?

Comment: As Mark says, if you have multiple instances running requests from the user may go to *any* of those instances. You may be better off with a single machine instance (e.g. google compute) initially.

Comment: @MarkSimpson I think I'm not understand mistaken for the instance. As our test, first my service running with two instance, once a user join the chat room, then the instance increase to 3, the new instance always handle this new join user because this user always have a loop for long polling likes:`while(1)
{
   usleep(500000);
  if(search someth in condition) 
 {
   echo json_encode（）; // send data to browser
 }

}`  does this code is wrong ?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood thanks, first we will the python with Channel API